# [CKEDITOR- Recreate ckeditor after destroy

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, multiple-instances, destroy, instances

I am unable to recreate ckeditor after destroy, and I found that few grouping plugins are causing issue like - justifygroup,indentgroup,listgroup,formatgroup,undogroup.

If I remove these plugins I am able to recreate editor after destroy, but I want to use these plugins. Any ideas?

Code snippet:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(editorID, {
    toolbarGroups: [
        {name: 'clipboard', groups: ['undo']},
        {name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles']},
        {name: 'links', groups: ['links']},
        {name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'align']},
        {name: 'insert', groups: ['insert']},
        {name: 'colors', groups: ['colors']},
        {name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools']},
        {name: 'styles', groups: ['styles']},
        {name: 'cleanup', groups: ['cleanup']}
    ],
    extraPlugins: 'scayt,image2,font,removeformat,youtube,confighelper,contextmenu,pastefromword,pastetext,tabletools,stylescombo,justify,colorbutton,colordialog,sourcearea,justifygroup,indentgroup,listgroup,formatgroup,undogroup,pastegroup',
    removePlugins: 'elementspath,resize,scayt',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/api/v1.0/uploadfile/' + projectID
});
```

Comment: are you destroying the instance like `if (CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName) CKEDITOR.instances.myInstanceName.destroy();`

Comment: Yes, basically I have 3 instances on modal, I am destroying it after closing modal like : 
for(k in CKEDITOR.instances){
CKEDITOR.instances[k].destroy();
}

Comment: and to reinitialize do you use the `config.js` file

Comment: to reinitialise I am using same code snippet added in above question.

Comment: so what error do you get ?